# When we talk about an 88/76/etc Key piano, does that include all keys or just white notes?

Tags: piano, keyboard

I have an old cheap keyboard which spans 5 octaves plus one extra C, so it goes from C2-C7 (I think).

Does that make this a 41 (5 x 8 +1) key or a 61 (5 x 12 + 1) keyboard?

When we talk about a standard 88-key piano is that the *total* number of white and black notes, meaning it covers just over 7 octaves?

While I'm here, what are the standard keyboard configurations if any other than a traditional piano can be said to be standard?

Comment: 'common standards' are' 88, 76 & as you've just discovered… 61 ;)

Comment: Good question - if the black keys disappeared, it would still be the same size!

Comment: If you google "how many keys on a piano", the *first* result says that *"Almost every modern piano has 52 white keys and 36 black keys for a total of 88 keys (seven octaves plus a minor third, from A0 to C8)."*. Note that your calculation (5 x 8 + 1) isn't how many white keys are on your keyboard, because there are *7* different white keys per octave, not 8. Your 5-octave keyboard has 36 white keys and 25 black keys for a total of 61 keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not hard to work out a number of keys when avoiding remembering this by heart.

A full piano has:

- 4 full octaves up from the middle C (C3)
- 3 full octaves down also from the middle C
- plus 3 additional keys at left next to C0.

An octave (e.g. from C3 to B3) contains 12 keys.

The number of keys:

- 3 extra keys at the left
- 3 octaves at the left, excluding the middle C, 12*3 = 36
- the middle C (C3)
- 4 octaves up make, excluding the middle C, 12*4 = 48

All together: 3 + 36 + 1 + 48 = 88

Answer (score 10):

An 88 key piano will have a TOTAL of 88 keys. White keys + black keys = 88.